# Downcast from '[NSIndexPath]?' to '[NSIndexPath]' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Tags: swift2

```
func backBtnAction(){

    var index = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems() as! [NSIndexPath]
    collectionView?.scrollEnabled = true
    collectionView?.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(index)
}
```

how to get `indexpath` in the `collectionview`... like I am doing

```
var index = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems() as! [NSIndexPath]
```

Answer (score 1):

`indexPathsForSelectedItems()` returns `[NSIndexPath]?` so the usual way is optional binding without casting

```
func backBtnAction() 
{
   if let indexes = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems() {
       collectionView!.scrollEnabled = true
       collectionView!.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexes)
   }
}
```